# What do you think the writer means by "Cold turkey"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Now I suppose I could have tried to gradually decrease my cell phone use at home, but that would have been too easy. Instead, I wondered If I could go a whole week with absolutely no cell phone. **Cold turkey**.
>   [*excerpt from an acticle written by Richard Rabkin*]

"Cold turkey"? What do you think the writer means by "Cold turkey"? I read this entry, but it didn't make sense:

> [Cold turkey](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/cold-turkey)
>   to withdraw from (an addictive substance or a habit) abruptly and completely.

Comment: The picture of the text isn't needed. Could you tell us which part you don't understand? Have you checked other dictionaries? For example, the same vocabulary item can be found in [this dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cold_turkey).

Comment: So why this definition doesn't make sense to you? He wants to stop using his cell phone for a whole week and he thinks that gradually decreasing is too easy for him, so he wants to stop this addictive habit abruptly and completely (for a week). This is  exactly what the definition of "Cold turkey" states.

Comment: I think you've already answered your own question - "cold turkey" means "abruptly and completely".

Comment: Per [dictionary,](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/cold-turkey) ***cold-turkey = abrupt withdrawal = detox[ification].*** What's so difficult about metaphorically comparing "addiction to mobile comms" wit addiction to hard drugs?

Comment: The author is describing how he's going to avoid using his cell-phone. Instead of gradually decreasing its use, he's planning to not use it at all, completely and abruptly ending its use during a week. Gradually vs. completely and abruptly [cold turkey]

Comment: @FumbleFingers This diversion, exactly, led me to considerable confusion. Why the writer wrote "Cold turkey" and then, after this, put a dot?

Comment: That could have been punctuated with an em-dash as well:   **—cold turkey.**  The syntactical starkness of that addendum to the sentence is mimetic of the starkness of the choice to go cold turkey—a grim experience indeed.

Comment: Are you asking about the *meaning in context*, or the punctuation / orthography?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Actually, both of them. My main question was meaning (which I got the answer), but this question has already came to mind. Is it common to use this expression (cold turkey I mean) for our habits in everyday English? Is it a complete sentence? Why should we use a dot?

Comment: So you *are* asking about the orthography as well as the semantics. Tricky. Personally, I have no particular opinion as to whether my use of the word "tricky" there represents a "complete sentence" or not - but obviously it's how people often talk, so we need *some* way of writing it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Cold turkey", indeed, makes no sense as a metaphor.  Neither the meat of the turkey, nor the animal itself, seems to have anything to do with quitting an addictive substance. Merriam-Webster quotes some who guess that "cold turkey" is meant to evoke the physical sensation of the process of serious opioid withdrawal:

> The most popular theory was repeated by the San Francisco Chronicle columnist Herb Caen in 1978: "It derives from the hideous combination of goosepimples [sic] and what William Burroughs calls 'the cold burn' that addicts suffer as they kick the habit." In Cop Speak: The Lingo of Law Enforcement and Crime, Tom Philbin recites a second theory, that "the term may derive from the cold, clammy feel of the skin during withdrawal, like a turkey that has been refrigerated." [source](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/why-do-we-quit-cold-turkey)

However, they discount these guesses, since the expression predates the first example of this use.

Etymology aside, the current meaning is to "kick a habit" by *completely quitting* the substance or behavior, that is to say *without any gradual decrease in usage*.  In your example, the author is saying that he plans to stop using his cell phone *all at once*, rather than a little at a time.

Another example:

> On New Year's Eve a few years ago my wife drank two-and-a-half bottles of wine, got gloriously, monstrously drunk, and woke up on New Year's Day with the mother of all hangovers.  That day she quit drinking alcohol **cold turkey** and hasn't touched a drop since.